# Работа со множествами

Tags: delphi

У меня есть множество чисел типа Bytes. Сколько элементов во множестве мне не известно. Мне нужно узнать среднее арифметическое значений чисел из этого множества. Как это сделать?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стандартных функций для этого не знаю. Во множестве не может быть больше 255-ти элементов. Если множество типа Byte, то я бы сделал так - три переменные целого типа - сумма, количество и счётчик цикла, мотаю цикл от 0 до 255 (промежуток значений типа Byte), если число находится во множестве, то прибавляю его к сумме и увеличиваю количество, после цикла делю сумму на количество.

Вот простая консольная программа:

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

Var
  MySet: Set Of Byte;
  i, N, k: Byte;
  Sum: LongWord;
  Sred: Extended;

begin
  Write('N = ');
  ReadLn(N);

  WriteLn;
  WriteLn('Tvoe mnojestvo:');
  WriteLn;

  Randomize;
  For i:=1 To N Do
    Begin
      k:=Random(256);
      If Not(k In MySet) Then
        Begin
          WriteLn(k);
          Include(MySet, K);
        End;
    End;

  WriteLn;

  k:=0;
  Sum:=0;
  For i:=0 To 255 Do
    If (i In MySet) Then
      Begin
        Sum:=Sum+i;
        Inc(k);
      End;

  Sred:=Sum/k;

  WriteLn;
  WriteLn('Sred = ', Sred:3:9);
  WriteLn;
  WriteLn('Davi na ENTER!');
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Comment: Вообще, множества уже считаются старыми...их очень редко применяют. 
Лучше использовать массивы. Они не ограничены 255 элементами, они используют меньшие вычислительные ресурсы...

---
@DelphiM0ZG, вы правы, таких функция нет, но они и не нужны...ведь данный функционал можно реализовать в три строчки кода =)

Comment: @Asen, я на самом деле чаще пользуюсь массивами (по Вами описанной причине), множествами в своей недолгой программерской практике воспользовался лишь пару-тройку раз. Их удобно использовать в тех случаях, когда требуется условие примерно такого типа: 10 <= x <= 40, где x - целое, чтобы не писать там оператор And.

Comment: Большое спасибо за код!!!

Comment: Как вообще можно сравнивать массивы и множества? Это различные структуры с совершенно различным назначением и различным занимаемым местом в памяти. Вы знаете, что массив байт размером 256 в представлении Set будет иметь всего 32 байта?

@Asen, а вы можете с массивами сделать так `MySet := [1,2,3] * [3,4];` и еще ряд интересных операций?

Более того, @DelphiM0ZG, вы знаете, что A + A = A? От вашей рандомизации в худшем случае в множестве будет только один элемент.

А еще мне интересно, как вы работаете с такими вещами, как TFontStyle, например, которых в Delphi масса и которые - множества.

Comment: На комментарий @Asen. Трудно удержаться. И это XXI век. Одно слово -- delphi

Comment: @Dex, знаю. TFontStyle - это не множество, это перечислимый тип( как enum в C++ ):

      Type
      types = (art1, art2, art3)

Насчет этого согласен:
      
       Это различные структуры

Comment: > множества уже считаются старыми...их очень редко применяют

Это - вздор.

> массивы ...  используют меньшие вычислительные ресурсы

Так обстоят дела в некоторых частных случаях, в общем же случае выигрыша в производительности либо нет, либо он ничтожен.

Comment: @Dex, я знаю, что A + A = A. Но, мой код, это же не инструкция по работе с множествами, а пример. Человеку понадобился пример кода, вот, я и написал, то, что первое пришло в голову. И вообще, как я сказал выше, множествами редко пользовался.

Comment: @karmadro4, я имел ввиду частный случай Delphi, не более.

@Asen, TFontStyles, прошу прощения, я имел ввиду этот тип. Который является множеством перечислимого типа TFontStyle, и с которым приходится работать.

Comment: По памяти я могу количественную оценку дать, массив флагов занимает в 8 раз больше множества. А по процессору примерно одинаково.